# Ajax move data to another div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to move data to another div after Ajax being refreshed. Every time it refreshed it get the new data from the database. I want to keep the old data that show up on the first div to be stored and when Ajax being refreshed again the first data from div will move to second div. And the first div will be replaced with new data.

this is HTML

```
                <td id="kue1" class="box" ></td>
                <td id="station1" class="box1"</td>
            <tr>

                <td id="kue2" class="box" ></td>
                <td id="station2" class="box1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="kue3" class="box"></td>
                <td id="station3" class="box1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="kue4" class="box"></td>
                <td id="station4" class="box1" ></td>
            </tr>
```

This is Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax",
        data: { QNum: 0 , station_num: 0 },
        success: function(data){

            var store = [];
            var textToBeDisplayed;
            var textToBeShowed;
            var e;


            if(data["q_play_list"] && Array.isArray(["q_play_list"])){
            var playList = data["q_play_list"];
            var playListLength = data["q_play_list"].length;

                for(var i = 0; i< playListLength; i++){
                 textToBeDisplayed = playList[i].QNum || "";
                 textToBeShowed = playList[i].station_num;


                 newData = playList[i].QNum;

                    if(playList[i].QNum == null && playList[i].station_num == null ){
                        console.log('do nothing');

                    }   

                    else if(textToBeDisplayed != null && textToBeShowed != null){
                        $('#kue1').text(textToBeDisplayed);
                        $('#station1').text(textToBeShowed);
                        textToBeDisplayed2 = textToBeDisplayed;
                        textToBeShowed2 = textToBeShowed;

                        console.log('got in123');
                    }

                    if($('#kue1').text().length >= 1 && $('#station1').text().length >= 1){

                        $('#kue2').text(textToBeDisplayed);
                        $('#station2').text(textToBeShowed);

                            console.log('got in1234');
                    }



                }
            } 

        console.log(data);

        },

        error: function (error) {
            console.log("something is wrong: ", error);
        }

    });
},10000)
});
```

But every time it refresh the data that store be like. The second div is changed just like the first that come out after refresh. I'm so confused i can't figured out. Is there solution to make it work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are populating `kue1`, `kue2` and `station1`, `station2` with same value that comes from AJAX request. You have to store old data that is present in `kue1` and `station1` in temporary variable and set kue1 and station1 with new values from AJAX. Later set kue2 and station2 from temporary variables.

Like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ajax",
    data: { QNum: 0 , station_num: 0 },
    success: function(data){

        var store = [];
        var textToBeDisplayed;
        var textToBeShowed;
        var e;
        let oldTextToBeDisplayed;
        let oldTextToBeShowed;


        if(data["q_play_list"] && Array.isArray(["q_play_list"])){
        var playList = data["q_play_list"];
        var playListLength = data["q_play_list"].length;

            for(var i = 0; i< playListLength; i++){
             textToBeDisplayed = playList[i].QNum || "";
             textToBeShowed = playList[i].station_num;


             newData = playList[i].QNum;

                if(playList[i].QNum == null && playList[i].station_num == null ){
                    console.log('do nothing');
                }   
                else if(textToBeDisplayed != null && textToBeShowed != null){
                    if ($('#kue1').text() == "" && $('#station1').text() == "") { // first time both keu1 and station1 will be empty
                        $('#kue1').text(textToBeDisplayed);
                        $('#station1').text(textToBeShowed);
                    }
                    else {
                        oldTextToBeDisplayed = $('#kue1').text();
                        oldTextToBeShowed = $('#station1').text();

                        $('#kue2').text(oldTextToBeDisplayed);
                        $('#station2').text(oldTextToBeShowed);

                        $('#kue1').text(textToBeDisplayed);
                        $('#station1').text(textToBeShowed);
                    }

                    console.log('got in123');
                }                    
            }
        } 

    console.log(data);

    },

    error: function (error) {
        console.log("something is wrong: ", error);
    }

});
},10000)
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: its worked. but i still don't understand, after it refresh loop will loop again and so when the new data come down shouldn't textToBeDisplayed and textToBeShowed both value changes ? and making the value on #kue1 and #station1 change too?

Comment: `textToBeDisplayed`  and `textToBeShowed` will change with whatever values that came from AJAX response in `playList[i]`. What is the length of `playList` you usually get against each AJAX request?

Comment: After looking into your code. Now i know how this works. thank you so much. i was confused at `oldTextToBeDisplayed = $('#kue1').text();` and `oldTextToBeShowed = $('#station1').text();` I didn't know that we could get text that show on html too. i thought we could only use `.text(by put some value)` on it. `playList[i].length`, it's the length of data filed from MySQL function. that i call. and sorry about my English

Comment: Good to know that it helped. You can have a look at http://api.jquery.com/ to see how `text()` and other jQuery functions works.